# Thymeleaf: Do you need to use th:field *{} on all fields?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

After adding a Model attribute in the `@GetMapping` do you need add all fields using `th:field="*{...}"` in the view's form?

For example, if I add a User to the model and I want a form that edits the name but not the DOB or anything else can I just use `th:field` on just the name and not include the other fields?

It still seems to work when I create a `@GetMapping` for edit I pass the model and just have the `th:field` for just the name, but online I see people adding all of the fields to the form.

I can understand if you are trying to save the Entity, but if you're editing does it make a difference that I just don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to use the `th:field="*{...}"` attribute on all fields.  Any fields  not specified will be reset to their empty or default value after the form is submitted.

This does mean that if you are editing an object and you leave a field off and save the object later, any fields without a `th:field` will be saved with an empty value.  (You can use the `@SessionAttributes` annotation to persist fields even if they don't appear on the form.)